# How to display data by using foreach in laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am displaying data in laravel view by using foreach loop.But the loop display's some thing [image: like this]

**Controller**

```
class StudViewController extends Controller {

public function index(){
    $studentList = DB::select('select * from student');
    // var_dump($studentList);
    return view('stud_view',['students'=>$studentList]);
}
```

}
?>

**View**

```
<!DOCTPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Student Records</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "1">
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>City Name</td>
<td>Email</td>
</tr>
@foreach ($students as $student)
<tr>
<td>{{ $student->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $student->first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $student->last_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $student->city_name }}</td>
<td>{{ $student->email }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

can any one try to help me.

Thank you

Comment: did you name your view template `yourfile.blade.php` ? or `yourfile.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing to name your view file correctly..

If you are using laravel blade template your view file name should be `stud_view.blade.php`

[Laravel Blade Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#introduction)

Comment: can you tell me what is blade

Comment: Please see the link from the answer..There is all details.